# Quarkus: Native image builds and runs tests with Maven outside of docker. However, when packaging native image into docker image get errors

Tags: quarkus

I'm able to compile and run tests without using Docker.  However, I get errors when trying to run inside a docker container.  It says something about not getting native version and the docker cgroup is not supported.

This works on my Fedora laptop:

```
./mvnw package -Pnative
```

This doesn't:

```
./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker -e
```

The following is the output.  Thanks for any help

```cs
 ./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< org.acme:getting-started >----------------------
[INFO] Building getting-started 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/bmullini/Documents/quarkus/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/bmullini/Documents/quarkus/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResourceTest
2020-05-20 09:51:55,660 WARN  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Using Java versions older than 11 to build Quarkus applications is deprecated and will be disallowed in a future release!
2020-05-20 09:51:56,692 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.4.2.Final started in 1.097s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-05-20 09:51:56,692 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated. 
2020-05-20 09:51:56,692 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.364 s - in org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResourceTest
2020-05-20 09:51:57,800 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus stopped in 0.029s
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:build (default) @ getting-started ---
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Using Java versions older than 11 to build Quarkus applications is deprecated and will be disallowed in a future release!
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building thin jar: /home/bmullini/Documents/quarkus/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/target/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 1014ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:native-image (default) @ getting-started ---
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Using Java versions older than 11 to build Quarkus applications is deprecated and will be disallowed in a future release!
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: /home/bmullini/Documents/quarkus/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/target/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from /home/bmullini/Documents/quarkus/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/target/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Pulling image quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11
19.3.1-java11: Pulling from quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image
Digest: sha256:9e2dd59c82db091bb90fd0ee60530291a5ecc201ebc718ffcc59ab0f406e47ea
Status: Image is up to date for quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11
quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11
[ERROR] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Unable to get GraalVM version from the native-image binary.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] docker run -v /home/bmullini/Documents/quarkus/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/target/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --env LANG=C --user 1000:1000 --rm quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11 -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Duser.language=en -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -jar getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:-IncludeAllTimeZones -H:EnableURLProtocols=http --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: this version of runc doesn't work on cgroups v2: unknown.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.556 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-20T09:52:02-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:native-image (default) on project getting-started: Failed to generate native image: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:353 undefined)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498 undefined)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:931 undefined)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277 undefined)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35 undefined)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046 undefined)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578 undefined)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452 undefined)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748 undefined)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479 undefined)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 125
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:369 undefined)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:339 undefined)
[ERROR]     ... 12 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:native-image (default) on project getting-started: Failed to generate native image
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61 undefined)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to generate native image
   at io.quarkus.maven.NativeImageMojo.execute (NativeImageMojo.java:308 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:353 undefined)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498 undefined)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:931 undefined)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452 undefined)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 125
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:369 undefined)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:339 undefined)
    ... 12 more
   at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment (AugmentActionImpl.java:247 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createProductionApplication (AugmentActionImpl.java:87 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.maven.NativeImageMojo.execute (NativeImageMojo.java:295 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61 undefined)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:353 undefined)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498 undefined)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:931 undefined)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452 undefined)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748 undefined)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 125
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:369 undefined)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:339 undefined)
    ... 12 more
   at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run (Execution.java:115 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute (BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run (QuarkusAugmentor.java:156 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment (AugmentActionImpl.java:245 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createProductionApplication (AugmentActionImpl.java:87 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.maven.NativeImageMojo.execute (NativeImageMojo.java:295 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406 undefined)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122 undefined)
   at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
   at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build (NativeImageBuildStep.java:353 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute (ExtensionLoader.java:931 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run (BuildContext.java:277 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run (ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun (EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask (EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run (EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452 undefined)
   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run (JBossThread.java:479 undefined)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 125
   at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed (NativeImageBuildStep.java:369 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build (NativeImageBuildStep.java:339 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute (ExtensionLoader.java:931 undefined)
   at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run (BuildContext.java:277 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run (ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun (EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask (EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run (EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452 undefined)
   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748 undefined)
   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run (JBossThread.java:479 undefined)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[bmullini@bmullini getting-started]$ cd $GRAALVM_HOME
[bmullini@bmullini graalvm]$ cd bin
[bmullini@bmullini bin]$ cd ..
[bmullini@bmullini graalvm]$ ls
ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  bin  GRAALVM-README.md  include  jre  lib  LICENSE_NATIVEIMAGE.txt  LICENSE.txt  man  release  sample  src.zip  THIRD_PARTY_LICENSE.txt  THIRD_PARTY_README
[bmullini@bmullini graalvm]$ gedit GRAALVM-README.md 
[bmullini@bmullini graalvm]$ gu install native-image
Downloading: Component catalog from www.graalvm.org
Processing Component: Native Image
Component Native Image (org.graalvm.native-image) is already installed.
[bmullini@bmullini graalvm]$ native-image --version
GraalVM Version 19.3.2 CE
```

Comment: Trying in podman

Answer (score -1):

You should switch to podman which is a cgroups v2 compatible service. See [here for more info](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F31_bugs#Docker_package_no_longer_available_and_will_not_run_by_default_.28due_to_switch_to_cgroups_v2.29).